# how can i remove sandboxing of iframe link when updating the data from admin django throgh ckeditor

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, ckeditor, sandbox

when i updating a data in any field of the model(model containing a field with ckeditor) the field containing iframe link has an error occured "
An error occurred.
Try watching this video on [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com), or enable JavaScript if it is disabled in your browser."
then i find that iframe was sandboxing when i submit ? how can i overcome it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqhmy.png)/NFgzg.png)

i want to remove the sandboxing of the iframe link